# Set the height of the vertical line (Developed in :after ) to a specific point, so that we don't have to readjust it over different devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical timeline 
Which have the boxes left and right

Similar to 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp
if you can see this I want the vertical timeline height to be on the last box circle it should not exceed the circle

What I have done so far :
I calculate the height from using

```
height: calc(100% - 640px);
```

and applied break points but this fails in different devices is there any way how can I achieve this

**Expected output Image**
[image]

Comment: Cannot tell what your exact problem is just by description. Share your HTML and CSS so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: the problem is when the card text is more the height which I calculated broke up